# Potential setups for Linux and windows vm, with gpu hotswap

Tags: linux, gpu, linux-kvm, hotswapping

### Hardware

I have a laptop with a 1tb hdd, a 256gb ssd, and an NVIDIA GTX 1050 gpu.

### My Question

is there a setup that would allow for:

1. Linux and a windows to run simultaneously, through KVM or the like*
2. The GPU to be hot swappable between OSs. Meaning the GPU would stay in the host machine, and the host has the ability to move the GPU virtually between OSs^

The Linux distro is not much of a concern, I'm currently using Arch, but if another distro is easier to do this kind of work I'm happy to broaden my knowledge

### What I've Investigated

UnRaid:
My main problem is the requirement of a USB to store config on, I may investigate a hack to remove this requirement, I also haven't found much evidence that hotswapping is possible

*Linux would run most of the time and would display the guest machines as windows, so could be used as the host
^virtual access would be good enough, ie. guest OSs attach to a virtual GPU, and the host distributes the load to the physical device

Comment: What exactly is a hot swappable gpu? You want to physically unplug a gpu and swap it with another one, while running an OS plus a VM?

Comment: Sorry, my aim is to leave the GPU in place, but be able to pass the device to different VMs. Like physically removing it and putting it in another machine, but virtually. I have updated my question to clarify